# How to get the instagram/flickr template when I share link on facebook for my website?

Tags: facebook, instagram, facebook-opengraph, flickr

How to have this type of template:

[image]

I tried to copy/paste the instagram opengraph codes but my shared posts have still the same layout.

Comment: Instagram is owned by Facebook, so they can presumably do stuff other, 3rd-party apps can’t. Your options are limited to what’s listed here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: but flickr is not and they have this specific template too

Comment: They still might get special treatment or perhaps be a Facebook partner. Doesn’t change the fact that your options are limited to what is listed in the documentation section I linked to.